# Coloring a levelplot according to an if-else-statement

Tags: r, if-statement, levelplot

This is a follow-up question that I have concerning a previous problem.
I visualized a 10x10 matrix and colored the squares in the `levelplot` according to their value.

This works out fine, however, I would also like to use an if-else-statement for coloring; i.e. if the square value is smaller a certain number the respective square should be colored red otherwise blue.

I am pretty sure this is a very easy problem - I just do not find a solution for it.

Here is an example code to see how it looks like now plus a picture.

```
library(lattice)

#Build the horizontal and vertical axis information

hor=c("0.0005", "0.001", "0.005", "0.01", "0.05", "0.1", "0.5", "1", "5", "10")
ver=c("1000","2000","3000","4000","5000","6000","7000","8000","9000","10000")

nrowcol=length(ver)
cor = matrix(runif(nrowcol*nrowcol, min=0.4), nrow=nrowcol, ncol=nrowcol, dimnames = list(hor, ver))
for (i in 1:nrowcol) cor[i,i] = 1

rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow"), space = "rgb")
levelplot(cor, col.regions=rgb.palette(120), cuts=100, at=seq(0,1,0.01),
          xlab=expression("DAG depletion rate k"[B49] *" [ s"^"-1"*" ]"),
          ylab=expression("PKC activation rate k"[D5] *" [ l / (mol*s) ]"))
```

Do you have a guess how I can fix this little issues?

[image]

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it should be a two-coloured plot (only red and blue squares)? Or should the gradients still be present?

Comment: yes, only two colors!

Comment: And does it have to be in lattice?

Comment: it would be a nice to have since other heatmaps of my work were also generated with levelplot; hence, the format of my work would be uniform.

Answer (score 2):

```
levelplot(cor < 0.5, col.regions=c("red", "blue"), cuts = 1, 
          xlab=expression("DAG depletion rate k"[B49] *" [ s"^"-1"*" ]"),
          ylab=expression("PKC activation rate k"[D5] *" [ l / (mol*s) ]"))
```

I'd not be satisfied with the legend, but I don't know how to change it to a discrete scale with lattice.

[image]